# Refresh ListView from another window

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm

It's the same problem as described here [Refresh combobox list from another window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292636/refresh-combobox-list-from-other-window-mvvm), but i have a ListView instead of ComboBox. I used the same method as described in the link above but it doesn't work correctly. My ListView has 6 columns and it is bound to MVVM property("Bookings"). Now the columns get data from 3 different database tables. After adding new booking only columns that get data from table "tblBookings" are filled with values, and columns that doesn't get data from this table are empty until I restart my window. Here is the code:

**BookingsViewModel:**

```
private bool isBookingSaved;
    public bool IsBookingSaved
    {
        get
        {
            return isBookingSaved;
        }
        set
        {
            isBookingSaved = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsBookingSaved");
        }
    }

 private string type;
    public string Type
    {
        get
        {
            return type;
        }
        set
        {
            type = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Type");
        }
    } 

    private ServiceReference1.tblBooking booking;
    public ServiceReference1.tblBooking Booking 
    {
        get 
        {
            return booking;
        }
        set 
        {
            booking = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Booking");
        }
    }

    private ServiceReference1.tblGuest guest;
    public ServiceReference1.tblGuest Guest
    {
        get
        {
            return guest;
        }
        set
        {
            guest = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Guest");
        }
    }

    private tblRoom room;
    public tblRoom Room
    {
        get
        {
            return room;
        }
        set
        {
            room = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Room");
        }
    }

 public ICommand _btnAddBooking;
    public ICommand btnAddBooking
    {
        get
        {
            if (_btnAddBooking == null)
            {
                _btnAddBooking = new DelegateCommand(delegate()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Service1Client wcf = new Service1Client();
                        wcf.AddBooking(Booking, Guest, Room, Type);
                        IsBookingSaved = true;
                        wcf.Close();


                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("working...", "MyApp");
                    }
                });
            }

            return _btnAddBooking;
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
 <ListView SelectionMode="Single" Height="428" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="lvReservations" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="654" BorderBrush="Black" SelectedItem= "{Binding Booking, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Bookings}" Foreground="Black" >
                    <ListView.View>

 <GridView.Columns>
                                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = tblGuest.Name}" Header="Ime i prezime" Width="240" />
                                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = tblRoom.RoomNo}" Header="Soba" Width="80"/>
                                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StartDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy.\}}" Header="Od" Width="100"/>
                                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EndDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yyyy.\}}" Header="Do" Width="100"/>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Aktivno">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsActive}" Name="IsActive" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding DataContext.Activated, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}" Click="CheckBox_Click" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Otkazano">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsCanceled}" Name="IsCanceled" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding DataContext.CanceledReservation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Click="CheckBox_Click" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                            </GridView.Columns>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
 private ObservableCollection<tblBooking> bookings;
    public ObservableCollection<tblBooking> Bookings
    {
        get
        {
            return bookings;
        }
        set
        {
            bookings = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Bookings");
        }
    }

 private tblBooking booking;
    public tblBooking Booking
    {
        get
        {
            return booking;
        }
        set
        {
            booking = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Booking");
        }
    }

public ICommand _btnAddReservation;
    public ICommand btnAddReservation
    {
        get
        {
            if (_btnAddReservation == null)
            {
                _btnAddReservation = new DelegateCommand(delegate()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        BookingsWindow bookings = new BookingsWindow();
                        bookings.ShowDialog();

                        var vm = bookings.DataContext as BookingsViewModel;
                        if (vm != null)
                        {
                            if (vm.IsBookingSaved)
                            {

                                var booking = vm.Booking as tblBooking;                                 

                                Booking = booking;
                                Bookings.Add(booking);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("working...", "MyApp");
                    }
                });
            }
            return _btnAddReservation;
        }
    }
```

For more description of a problem leave a comment and I'll be more specific.
Regards.

**EDIT:**

Wcf service:

```
bool IService1.AddBooking(tblBooking booking, tblGuest guest, tblRoom room, string type)
    {
        try
        {
            context = new HotelBaseEntities();
            tblBooking book = new tblBooking();
            tblStayGuest stayGuest = new tblStayGuest();

            tblRoom rm = (from r in context.tblRooms where r.RoomID == room.RoomID select r).FirstOrDefault();

            book.GuestID = guest.GuestID;
            book.RoomID = room.RoomID;
            rm.RoomStatus = true;

            book.StartDate = booking.StartDate;
            book.EndDate = booking.EndDate;
            book.PansionType = type;

            stayGuest.IsMainGuest = true;
            book.IsActive = false;
            book.IsCanceled = false;

            guest.IsCheckedOut = false;
            context.AddTotblBookings(book);
            context.SaveChanges();

            return true;
        }
```

tblStayGuests is table which defines the guests that are currently in hotel. It is not immportant for my problem. As you can see in my binding I bound ListView's items source to "Bookings" property and the columns that get the data from other columns are bound like: "Bookings.tblGuest.Name" for example. Columns that are bound like that does not get refreshed until i reopen my window. That's the problem i'm trying to solve.

Comment: So when I click the button to add a reservation from the MainWindow how does the ListView not updating? I can't understand the scenario. If the button is on the MainWindow then I should be able to add it to the database then load the BooksWindowDialog and have the updated ListView.

Comment: No, the ListView is inside the MainWindow and i have a button that opens new window (Bookings Window) where i have form for adding new bookings. ListView in MainWindow have those records and it needs to be updated every time I add new record in Bookings Window.

Comment: How does your private ObservableCollection<tblBooking> bookings gets instantiated?

Comment: What does tblBooking look like? When you add the booking to the list, do its tblGuets and tblRooms properties have values?

Comment: tblBooking has columns that describes the period of reservation: "StartDate" and "EndDate" (names of the columns in database), also has column that defines pansion type("PansionType") and boolean columns "IsActive" and "IsCanceled" which defines weather the booking is active or canceled. This table is related with tables "tblGuests" and "tblRooms". I add booking to database via WCF service. I'll edit my question to show you the code of the method on WCF service.